# Integrate my custom mediator with WSO2 ESB log4j

Tags: log4j, wso2

I am writing my own custom mediator. In my custom mediator, I use log4j to log the process.. 
But I am facing difficulties now when deploy the custom mediator in WSO2. 
What I want is the log in my custom mediator will be written in the "wso2carbon.log". But unfortunately I still have no clue how to do that. 
Do I need to configure the log4j.properties here? or do I need to implement or extends something in my custom mediator? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this can also be done by adding the package name along with log type needed in the log4j.properties. Doing it through the management console is also an option and you can refer http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Setting+Up+Logging to get an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this using the Management Console in WSO2. In my custom mediator I use the 'info' level, and in WSO2 I think the custom mediator will have the default 'error' level. So I change the level to 'info' level, and the log is shown in the wso2 log file :)